# Vacation accrual calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to write logic that will calculate vacation accrual that begins after one year of service. At y1 employees are eligible for 5 days, at y2 10 days until the employee reaches y7 where the employee is entitled to 15 days plus one additional day on each anniversary year until the employee caps at y12 20 days. My formula continues to indicate too many arguments.

Comment: Can you post the formula? Use 4 spaces on a new line to start a code snippet.

Comment: what version of Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `VLOOKUP`.

In the formula below, the array constant is the equivalent of a table with years of service in column 1, and the days of vacation in column 2.  I also assumed that years 2-6 also had 10 days vacation, but if not, you can see where to change easily enough:

```
=VLOOKUP(YrsOfSvc,{1,5;2,10;3,10;4,10;5,10;6,10;7,15;8,16;9,17;10,18;11,19;12,20},2)
```

and `YrsOfSvc` is whatever cell that information is located, or a number.

If, in fact, your accrued days does not increase during years 3-6, you can shorten the array a bit:

```
=VLOOKUP(YrsOfSvc,{1,5;2,10;7,15;8,16;9,17;10,18;11,19;12,20},2)
```

If you want to do this by calculation, you can use the formula below.  But if changes are required, this would be a bit more difficult to maintain:  (`A2 = YrsOfSvc`)

```
=MIN(20,IF(A2>=7,15+A2-7,IF(A2>=2,10,IF(A2=1,5,0))))
```

Comment: That is quite the hard coded array there Ron.  I think I would have gone with a table with approximate match.  Kudos to you for keeping it straight!

Comment: @ForwardEd Thanks. I wasn't sure, from his description, whether accrued time stayed the same or increased during the period from 2-7 years, so I included each year separately.  But I've also posted a shortened variant, for the reason you point out.